# Why my output is showing the locations instead of the names of ingredients?

Tags: java, arrays, output

```
 class Food {
        private String name;
        private String []ingredients;
        private double price;
        private float calories;
        
        public Food (){
        }
    
        public Food (String name, String [] ingredients, double price, float calories){
            this.name= name;
            this. ingredients= ingredients;
            this.price=price;
            this.calories= calories;
    
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
        }
        public void setIn(String[] ingredients){
            this.ingredients=ingredients;
        }
        public void setPrice (double price){
            this.price= price;
        }
        public void setCalories(float calories){
            this.calories = calories;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        public String[] getIn(){
            return ingredients;
        }
        public double getPrice(){
            return price;
        }
        public float getCalories(){
            return calories;
        }
    
    
    
    }

   
 

    class Burger extends Food {
        private int numberofPatty;
        public Burger(){
    
    
        }
        public Burger(String name, String[] ingredients, double price,float calories, int numberofPatty){
            super(name,ingredients,price,calories);
            this.numberofPatty= numberofPatty;
    
        }
        public void setNP(int numberofPatty){
            this.numberofPatty= numberofPatty;
        }
        public int getNP(){
            return numberofPatty;
        }
        public void showdetails(){
            System.out.println("Name="+getName());
            System.out.println("In="+ getIn());
            System.out.println("Price="+getPrice());
            System.out.println("Calories="+getCalories());
            System.out.println("NP="+numberofPatty);
    
        }
        
    }
    
  
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            String[] burgerIngredients = new String[2];
    
            burgerIngredients[0]= new String("alu");
            burgerIngredients[1]= new String("Potato");
    
    
    
            Burger burger1 = new Burger("Classic Burger", burgerIngredients, 5.99, 550, 1);
            
    
        
    
    
        burger1.showdetails();
        
        }

}
```

thats the burger class, showdetails is the output i want

i tried array concept. what should i do to get the output with ingredients name?.........................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You haven't shown all the code, crucially what's in the`Burger` class. I _suspect_ you're just printing out the array and you should instead be iterating over the elements and printing those.

Comment: To print array elements you can refer to this question: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: Also, note that you don't need to use `new String("..")` to create a string; you can just use a string literal (e.g. `"Potato"`).

Comment: do you mean it is printing something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@887af79` ? (that would not [necessarily] be the location, BTW)

Comment: @ndc85430 i am not allowed to paste the full code for some reason idk why. I'm pure noob here

Comment: @user85421 exactly that is what the output is showing

Comment: @tgdavies yes. i tried that way and its working now, i'm trying to understand the process. why creating objects and assigning it doesn't work?

Comment: @everyone thanks. i thought i would have to wait 2 days for any productive answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use get method to print all ingredient details.

```
public String[] getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
}
```

It would be helpful if you can show burger class like using showdetails() u wanted to print ingredient details?

Comment: @roli_agrawal i added the Burger class. please check

Comment: If u are using food class then put food class as well. Without proper code its hard to tell issue here